# Just realised (a bit late) that Security's Blog is mis-titled

Tags: bug, design, blog

When we revised [Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/)'s name from IT Security to Information Security, we forgot to change both the title and sidebar on our [blog](http://security.blogoverflow.com/) .

[image]

Can we have that updated, please?

Comment: How long has this been there then? :P

Comment: Erm... October 2013 was when we officially renamed the site... :-)